# can't set image size correctly with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have a problem fitting my image into my ImageView ,I use PagerContainer and an Image view below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/container">

    <com.cinecitta.Gallery.PagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"

        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </com.cinecitta.Gallery.PagerContainer>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager_container"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Every thing works fine and i see my image but it's not scaled to the size of the imageView.

This is my instantiateItem for the pager container:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    ImageView pageView = new ImageView(PagerActivity.this);

    Picasso.with(PagerActivity.this).load(images.get(position))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(pageView);

    container.addView(pageView);

    return pageView;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `centerInside()`.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: I am not absolutely certain this is the solution but I found this in a very similiar situation in our codebase: `container.addView(photoView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` I suppose without the `LayoutParams` the `ImageView` you are instantiating in your code will just not fill the whole area of the `ViewPager`.